# LINQ GroupBy a List according to a key inside dictionary inside dictionary inside List C#

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

I am Creating a list that has dictionaries of dictionaries for creating Json with it from a wcf service.

im creating like this:

```
List<Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, Object>>> superduperList = new List<Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, Object>>>();
```

Im filling it with data and the Json Looks like this:

```
[
{
DepartureJ: {},
ReturnJ: {},
pricesDepartureJ: {},
pricesReturnJ: {},
DepartureSegmentsJ: {},
ArrivalSegmentsJ: {}
},
...,
...,
...,
...,
...,
]
```

the starting Array is the List

the first Object is the Dictionary of Dictionaries 
and the Objects Within the First Dictionary are again Dictionaries with Key/Value Pairs String/object
(i use object because the type could be bool or int or string)
now a dictionary in the last level looks like this:

```
   "DepartureJ": {
        ArrivalDateTime: "2013-09-27T12:15:00",
        ArrivalDateTime_str: "12:15",
        StopQuantity: 0,
        StopQuantity_str: "Direct",
        TotalDuration: "50",
        TotalDuration_str: "0h 50mins",
        SeatsRemaining_str: "2",
        NoBag_str: "",
        NonRefundable: true,
        NonRefundable_str: "Non Refundable",
        FareBasisCode: "xxx-",
        RoutingId: "",
        GroupCompStr: "ATH-SKG-1xxxxxx-UOWA3--0",
        LineCompStr: "-2013-09xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxA3--3,0000000-1-0--",
        TotalAmount_From_Prices: 136.64
    }
```

Now My Question is how do i Sort the Outer List From the Key TotalAmount_From_Prices which lies inside the dictionary of each dictionary of each item of the list?

i tried with groupby with LINQ but not working or don't know how :s

```
superduperList.GroupBy(each_result=> each_result["DepartureJ"]["TotalAmount_From_Prices"]);
```

its ok if i create a new list or change the existing.

Comment: Are you only trying to sort the inner dictionaries or does the outer dictionary need to be sorted as well? Meaning... if outer contains Dict1 and Dict2, Dict1 contains TotalAmount val 1, 2 and Dict 2 contains val 3, 1... What should the result be, just outer dictionary that contains sorted Dict1 (1, 2) and Dict (1, 3) or are you attempting to sort the outer dictionary as well?

Comment: I want to sort only the outer List but depending on the Key of the inner/inner Dict and the Dicts are specific

Comment: Your dictionaries contain object, so you'll want to cast the value to a double. You'll also want to make sure that it is stored as a double when parsing the json into your data structure.

Comment: i will try it. how do i cast it in to double? with (double) ?
Or convert.ToDouble() ?
Also it is always filling this value with double so its ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well actually i did it in a different manner.

I created a custom Class to hold the data as following:

```
public class each_flight
{
    public Dictionary<string, object> DepartureJ = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    public Dictionary<string, object> ReturnJ = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    public Dictionary<string, object> pricesDepartureJ = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    public Dictionary<string, object> pricesReturnJ = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    public Dictionary<string, object> DepartureSegmentsJ = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    public Dictionary<string, object> ArrivalSegmentsJ = new Dictionary<string, object>();

    public double total_price;

}
```

and then i created:

```
List<each_flight> flights = new List<each_flight>();
```

and then i populated the objects in the list and then with the extra double total_price i sorted them like this:

```
List<each_flight> Fligths_sorted = flights.OrderBy(o => o.total_price).ToList();
```

so its ok now :)